# Django nginx and append slashes problem

Tags: django, apache, nginx

I am trying to use nginx as a simple load balancer for django per Jacob Kaplan-Moss' example:
http://github.com/jacobian/django-deployment-workshop 
http://python.mirocommunity.org/video/1689/pycon-2010-django-deployment-w

If I stop nginx and have apache listen on port 80 everything works fine.  If I have apache listening to nginx my urls break.

When nginx is running, http://184.106.***.***/admin/ works, but http://184.106.***.***/admin (missing ending slash) breaks. It redirects to the name of the web server http://web1/admin/

I know it is nginx causing the issue because the redirect works fine in apache and django dev server.

Here is the nginx.conf that is running:

```
# Nginx conf (/etc/nginx/nginx.conf).

#
# Basic setup
#

user www-data;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;

#
# Event/worker setup.
#

worker_processes 4;
events {
    worker_connections 100;
}

#
# HTTP configuration
#

http {
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;

    # HTTP upstream for load balancers.
    # Replace the IPs below with IPs (or names) of your upstream Apaches
    upstream sitename {
        server 10.X.X.X:8000;
        server 10.X.X.X:8000;
    }

    # The actual HTTP sever.
    server {
        listen 80;

        # Don't proxy static files like robots.txt and favicon.ico.
        location ~ ^/(favicon.ico|robots.txt|sitemap.xml)$ {
            alias /home/web/static/$1;
        }

        # Serve media directly out of Nginx for performance
        location /media {
            alias /home/media;
        }

        # Proxy everything else to the backend
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://sitename;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;      
            add_header X-Handled-By $upstream_addr;      
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it safe to assume you have a `server_name` on that `server` block somewhere? That's the first odd thing I see, though I don't see how it would cause the problem you describe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the exact same problem you had, following Jacob's nginx example, and not having a slash would cause improper redirects.  pjmorse's response helped me, I set the server_name in the server block ( server { server_name: vasir.net; .... ) and it fixed the problem.  However, I had to restart the server first and

Comment: Sorry, just getting back to this.  Where do you set the server name?  I tried in the "server" directive in the nginx config, but it causes errors.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  Had a couple of issues, so going to post here. Put the server names in the "server {" directive in nginx.conf AFTER "listen 80;" and it will look like "server_name yourdomain.com alias www.yourdomain.com;"